# SQLite Update Query Not Working

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm running an update query that compiles. But when I test the results, there seem to be no changes. Everything looks good to me, but clearly something is wrong. Can anyone see what I am missing. Pretty new to SQLite, so apologies if it's something simple. Thanks!

```
public static Boolean updateHealth (int unitVal, int oldValue, int newValue) {
    String unit = Integer.toString(unitVal);
    String oldVal = Integer.toString(oldValue);
    String newVal = Integer.toString(newValue);

    System.err.printf("old val: %s, new val: %s\n", oldVal, newVal);
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String where = UNIT_COLUMN + " = " + unit + " AND " + HEALTH_COLUMN + " = " + oldVal;

    Cursor cursor = db.query(UNITS_TABLE, new String[] {UNIT_COLUMN}, where, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        /* the record doesn't exist, cancel the operation */
        return false;
    }

    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
    updatedValues.put(HEALTH_COLUMN, newVal);

    /* SQL query clauses */
    String whereArgs[] = null;

    db.update(UNITS_TABLE, updatedValues, where, whereArgs);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? What do you expect to happen? Can you give a specific example?

Comment: `if (cursor != null)` should always apply. The `Cursor` may be empty in some cases `cursor.getCount() == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor is not null when no row is retrieved. So you have to replace the line `if (cursor != null) {` by `if(!cursor.moveToNext()) {`
By the way, you don't need to query the database before updating. You can do the update, see how many rows have been affected and return true if the number of affected rows is > 0, false otherwise. The number of affected rows is returned by the method `update`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. I'm very curious how I would check to see how many rows are affected during an update query. I could make this code a bit simpler. Thanks again!